# using context to register and unregister receivers for Broadcast receiver in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, nested-class

I have a nested class that does not extend Activity or Service, however this inner class has a Broadcast receiver that is used to receive broadcast intents.

since this class does not have any onCreate or onDestroy callback methods inside it. I was told that i can somehow use context passed from the Activity class to this inner class, and use that context to register the receiver.

how can I do that?

Comment: Doesn't look like a good design decision to me, probably you should try to review your application architecture to avoid applying some kind of hacks to solve your problem.

Comment: yes, I think a change in this application design is in order.  Just looking at the code gives me the chills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the outer class instance like this : `Context context = OuterClassNameActivity.this`.